# Getting estimate and p-value into dataframe

Tags: r

I am fairly new to R. My data looks something like this (only with 9000 columns and 66 rows)

```
Time <- c(0, 6.4, 8.6, 15.2, 19.4, 28.1, 42.6, 73, 73, 85, 88, 88, 88, 88, 88)
ID1 <- c(55030, 54539, 54937, 48897, 58160, 54686, 55393, 47191, 39805, 37601, 51328, 28882, 45587, 60061, 31892, 28670)
ID2 <- c(20485, 11907, 10571, 20974, 10462, 11149, 20970, NA, NA, 9295, NA, 8714, 24446, 10748, 9037, 11859)
ID3 <- c(93914, 44482, 43705, 51144, 49485, 43908, 44324, 37342, 18872, 39660,61673, 43837, 36528, 44738, 41648, 11100)
DF <- data.frame (Time, ID1, ID2, ID3)
```

I want to get a data frame that looks like this :

ID1, rho, p-value

ID2, rho, p-value

...

The rho and the p-value would be the results from a cor.test (spearman) with Time and each ID

Among other things I've tried this:

```
results <- data.frame(ID="", Estimate="", P.value="")
estimates = numeric(16)
pvalues = numeric(16)
for (i in 2:4){
  test <- cor.test(DF[,1], DF[,i])
  estimates[i] = test$estimate
  pvalues[i] = test$p.value
}
```

And R gives me the following error:

```
Error: object 'test' not found
```

I've also tried:

```
result <- do.call(rbind,lapply(2:4, function(x) {
  cor.result<-cor.test(DF[,1],DF[,x])
  pvalue <- cor.result$p.value
  estimate <- cor.result$estimate
  return(data.frame(pvalue = pvalue, estimate = estimate))
})
)
```

And R gives me a similar error

```
Error: object 'cor.result' not found
```

I'm sure it's an easy fix but I can't seem to figure it out. Any help is more than welcome.

This is what I got after running

```
dput(head(SmallDataset[,1:5]))

structure(list(Species = c("Human.hsapiens", "Chimpanzee.ptroglodytes", 
"Gorilla.ggorilla", "Orangutan.pabelii", "Gibbon.nleucogenys", 
"Macaque.mmulatta"), Time = c(0, 6.4, 8.61, 15.2, 19.43, 28.1
), ID1 = c(55030, 54539, 54937, 48897, 58160, 54686), ID2 = c(20485, 
11907, 10571, 20974, 10462, 11149), ID3 = c(93914, 44482, 43705, 
51144, 49485, 43908)), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Comment: You are trying to calculate correlations between your ID variables in columns 2 to 4 of DF and Time? Is that correct?

Comment: I am trying to correlate the first column with the rest, as in 1st and 2nd, 1st and 3rd, 1st and 4th

Answer (score 1):

My solution involves defining a function within a lapply call

```
##
library(dplyr)

###Create dataframe
Time <- c(0, 6.4, 8.6, 15.2, 19.4, 28.1, 42.6, 73, 73, 85, 88, 88, 88, 88, 88, 89)
ID1 <- c(55030, 54539, 54937, 48897, 58160, 54686, 55393, 47191, 39805, 37601, 51328, 28882, 45587, 60061, 31892, 28670)
ID2 <- c(20485, 11907, 10571, 20974, 10462, 11149, 20970, NA, NA, 9295, NA, 8714, 24446, 10748, 9037, 11859)
ID3 <- c(93914, 44482, 43705, 51144, 49485, 43908, 44324, 37342, 18872, 39660,61673, 43837, 36528, 44738, 41648, 11100)
DF <- data.frame (Time, ID1, ID2, ID3)

##Run the correlations
l2 <- lapply(2:4, function(i)cor.test(DF$Time, DF[,i]))

##Define function to extract p_value and coefficients
l3 <- lapply(l2, function(i){
  return(tibble(estimate = i$estimate,
         p_value = i$p.value))
})

##Create a dataframe with information
l4 <- bind_rows(l3) %>% mutate(ID = paste0("ID", 1:3)) ##Data frame with info

l4
```

Comment: You could also use the `tidy` function from the `broom` package to extract the estimates and p.values. `sapply(2:4, function(i) {
  cor.test(DF$Time, DF[,i]) %>% 
    tidy() %>% 
    select(estimate, p.value)
  }) %>% 
  t() %>% 
  as.data.frame() %>% 
  mutate(ID = paste0("ID", 1:3))`

Comment: Will edit to reflect that. Thanks for flagging @Parfait

Comment: Thank you, it works on the small DF, but when I try to apply it to the larger one I get this error: 'x' and 'y' must have the same length , even though if I ask for the length of both elements it says it's the same length

Comment: Where is it specifically breaking? When you run the correlations? When you extract the coefficients? Or when you create the last data frame

Comment: It breaks when I run l2: l2 <- lapply(3:11, function(i)cor.test(SmallDataset$Time, SmallDataset[,i]))
Traceback:
 Error in cor.test.default(SmallDataset$Time, SmallDataset[, i]) : 
  'x' and 'y' must have the same length 
5.
stop("'x' and 'y' must have the same length") 
4.
cor.test.default(SmallDataset$Time, SmallDataset[, i]) 
3.
cor.test(SmallDataset$Time, SmallDataset[, i]) 
2.
FUN(X[[i]], ...) 
1.
lapply(3:11, function(i) cor.test(SmallDataset$Time, SmallDataset[, 
    i]))

Answer (score 0):

Consider building a list of data frames witih `lapply` (an iteration function similar to `for` but builds a list of objects  of equal length as input). Afterwards, row bind all data frame elements together:

```
results <- lapply(2:4, function(i){      
  test <- cor.test(DF[,1], DF[,i])

  data.frame(ID = names(DF)[i],
             estimate =  unname(test$estimate),
             pvalues = unname(test$p.value))      
})

final_df <- do.call(rbind, results)
final_df

#    ID   estimate     pvalues
# 1 ID1 -0.6238591 0.009805341
# 2 ID2 -0.2270515 0.455676037
# 3 ID3 -0.4964092 0.050481533
```

NOTE: Your posted data for *Time* is missing an observation and cannot immediately be cast into `data.frame()` with other vectors. To resolve, I supplemented a 6th 88 at end:

```
Time <- c(0, 6.4, 8.6, 15.2, 19.4, 28.1, 42.6, 73, 73, 85, 88, 88, 88, 88, 88, 88)
```

Using posted SmallDataset:

```
SmallDataset <- structure(...)

results <- lapply(3:5, function(i){      
  test <- cor.test(SmallDataset$Time, SmallDataset[,i])

  data.frame(ID = names(SmallDataset)[i],
             estimate =  unname(test$estimate),
             pvalues = unname(test$p.value))      
})

final_df <- do.call(rbind, results)
final_df

#    ID    estimate   pvalues
# 1 ID1  0.03251407 0.9512461
# 2 ID2 -0.41733336 0.4103428
# 3 ID3 -0.60732484 0.2010166
```

Comment: Thank you, but when I try it on the larger dataframe I get this : Error in cor.test.default(SmallDataset[, 2], SmallDataset[, i]) : 
  'x' must be a numeric vector. Even though all vectors are numeric

Comment: Please edit your post with a sample of *SmallDataset* in your post (first few rows and cols): `dput(head(SmallDataset[,1:5]))`. It will look like gobbledygook but we know how to use it. We can help format in your post as well.

Comment: I am unable to reproduce any issue with the small sample. See update. Did you properly replace all `DF` with `SmallDataset`? Be sure names and column numbers are correct.

Comment: So DF I made manually from the SmallDataset. So maybe there the type of data changes. SmallDataset is a 66 lines and 11 column frame. I triple checked all names and columns and I still get the same error

Comment: The only reason why it wouldn't be the same length is the NA s but in the original post there were already some and it worked fine.

Comment: Can you post the entire dataset in rextester.com (selecting 'R' for language), pastebin.com, GitHub gist, some other copy/paste tool: `SmallDataset <- structure(...)` and send link?

Comment: Sorry I'm really new at this. How can I post the dataset if it's an excel sheet?

Comment: Use `dput` like you just did! Open [rextester](https://rextester.com/l/r_online_compiler), select R language, delete the default lines, type `SmallDataset <- structure(...)` (where `structure` is copy and pasted from your `dput(SmallDataset)`). Then print `SmallDataset` to see result. Once done, click Save to generate a link.

Comment: Using your exact data, my solution works without any issue: https://rextester.com/WHEG96458.

Comment: Got it! The problem was that for some reason my data was a tibble instead of a dataframe in my computer! Thank you so much!